# Android change specific words on TextView from Java or XML

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, textview

Since Android XML layouts are all rectangular, how can I have **just some parts** of the TextView with different font sizes and params?

In the example below, the time (which is in grey and has a smaller font size) is always at the end of the text. I don't know how to reproduce this in XML. If I separate the text in two different textviews and the width of both were `wrap content` it would just appear at the right of the `TextView` Layout (at the right of every line from the main message, not at the end).

Is it possible to do this layout configuration with XML or do I need to do it programmatically using JAVA? How can I change the params of certain parts of a textview with Java?

[image]

With two TextViews and Wrap Content (not what I want):

[image]

Comment: i don't really see what the problem is with this, why can't you achieve this with xml ? could you show what you've tried so far ? this seems easy to do with two textviews using constraint layout, but even linear layout would work ? alternatively, you can look at [spannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) but that would be overkill for this i believe

Comment: @a_local_nobody I changed the question with the layout with two textviews with wrap content

Comment: ahh actually, i understand your problem now, yeah the fact that the views are rectangular makes this trickier, perhaps have a look at spannableString

Comment: can you post your xml here?

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your question is you want a single textView with multiple style inside this. to do so you can do this:

```
 SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder(); // a spannable string builder

    text.append("your friend "); // appending first text
    SpannableString fname = new SpannableString("Joana"); //making a span that would have different style
    fname.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, fname.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // set different style
    text.append(fname); // append value
    text.append(" his sending you a message      ");
    SpannableString time_ago = new SpannableString("41 min ago"); //another span
    time_ago.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.7f), 0, time_ago.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    time_ago.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, time_ago.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    text.append(time_ago); // append value
    
    textView.setText(text);
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/tvtest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image: output]

Comment: @ludicrous did it help?